# How to decrypt a MultiBit private key?

Tags: multibit

Looking for a way to decrypt a private key that was exported by Multibit WITHOUT using Multibit. I need to move they key elsewhere.

I need to go this route because I can't get the key to import into Multibit properly (even though I have the password).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process to decrypt a password protected .key file exported using MultiBit is explained here: https://github.com/jim618/multibit/wiki/Export%20and%20limited%20import%20of%20private%20keys

To decrypt a MultiBit private key export file use:

```
openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -a -in \<ciphertext file\> -out \<plaintext file\> -pass pass:\<password\>
```

Comment: @ Luca Matteis, What do you put in \<password\ ? Thx